# Intent won't reset extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity that gets a string through intent extras:

```
i.putExtra("static_image", theUri.toString());
startActivity(i);
```

in my activity:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("static_image");
```

It works, but if I don't close the app and I open that activity again with a different uri, the intent gives me the old one...

I think the intent is being reused. How can I reset the activity or force the activity to use the new intent?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK this solved my problem.
in the receiver activity override:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about if you remove it from the intent, right away after you retrieve it?

```
// test if it exists?    
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("static_image");

// ......
// remove it since you already have it in your variable
getIntent().removeExtra("static_image");
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't work... I have no extra at the next start :P